# Eevee Smoke invisible on objects

Tags: node-editor, smoke-simulation, eevee-render-engine

Smoke looks too thin when it is on the small square plane. Here is upside-down view and Flow object (small square) settings:

[image: Flow object]

And this is side view and Domain object settings:

[image: Domain object]

Why is it so, and how can I make the smoke look better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the following parameters influence on smoke's density above other objects:

1. **Density** value in Volume Principled shader (it should be between 30-60)
2. **High Resolution** mode in Domain object settings (using this, you can set Density 1.5-2 times smaller)
3. Volumetric scene settings -> Volumetric Lighting -> **Light Clamping**. It should about 10-15, or zero (no clamping). Using this parameter you can easily control the **brightness** of the smoke separately from the density.

And of course the light must be good.

Here is what I've got with Density 30, Light Clamping 10, HighRes turned on, and Sun light energy 10:

[image: Result]